# Подгрузка html-кода

Tags: html

Вот у меня есть "header". Он повторяется на каждой странице. Могу ли я Создать отдельный html-файл, прописать там структуру исключительно "шапки", а затем вставлять его на другие страницы?
Видел что-то такое:

```
***
title:123
***
```

При редакции шапки, она должна меняться на всех страницах...
Сайт стаит на хостинге github - pages
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Можно сделать используя PHP

Comment: Как я понял PHP будет вместо html? Но у меня страницы прописаны на языке html...

Comment: Нет, В просто в PHP надо указать имя файла откуда брать шапку. А после пиши остальную страницу.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: Сейчас напишу как надо

Comment: Можно с помощью какого-нибудь фронтенд фреймворка, например, реакт. Чуть позже напишу.

Comment: github pages поддерживает статические генераторы: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#static-site-generators

Answer (score 3):

Файл шапки header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
```

Страница 1

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>
    <h1>Страница 1</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Страница 2

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>
    <h1>Страница 2</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Также можно добавить footer, но тогда надо заменить `</body></html>` на `<?php include 'footer.php';?>` в файлах страниц.
footer.php

```
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +/- понял, сейчас посижу, и может пойму)
Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @EnderToy include/require он получает содержимое файла то-есть html код

Answer (score 1):

Это также можно реализовать на стороне фронтенда. Вот мое решение с использование react.js и библиотеки react-router-dom:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Main from './Pages/Main/Main'; // Импортируем различные странички
import News from './Pages/News/News';

import Header from './Components/Header/Header'; // Импортируем наш хедер

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Header />               // Здесь мы подключаем хедер. Он вне Switch'а, поэтому будет присутствовать на всех страницах
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact>  // В роутах мы указываем путь, делая запрос на который нам будет выдаваться страничка. Это все должно быть внутри <Switch></Switch>.
                        <Main />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/news" exact>
                        <News />
                    </Route>
                    <Redirect to="/" /> // Редирект срабатывает, если путь не соответствует ни "/", ни "/news".
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Очень заинтересовал ваш вариант, но не пойму как его использовать... Если не сложно, можете пояснить?
У меня есть, условно, index.html, в нем <head> и <body>.
Нужно создать js-файл и подключить его или прописать в "голове" страницы?
А каком виде нужно делать шапку, html?

Comment: Реакт - фреймворк для фронтенда, очень сильно упрощает и облегчает с ним работу. Могу предложить несколько ссылок: [monsterlessons](https://monsterlessons.com/project/lessons/?page=2&search=react) - вбиваете в поиск `react`, советую смотреть с первого урока, [официальная документация React](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) на русском языке.

Answer (score 0):

Так, как в вопросе не указано, на чём написан сервер, то буду говорить про node.js. Для таких задач используются движки представлений, такие как [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), [ejs](https://ejs.co/) и другие. Они "собирают" конечный файл, который будет отправлен браузеру.
Это же справедливо и для других платформ, только там иные инструменты.

Comment: Я использую github - pages для хостинга.
Поскольку я плох в этом, не хочу лезть в js.
Но спасибо за ответ

Comment: @EnderToy, если вы используете github pages, то у вас не будет работать и php. Кстати, в данном случае это важная деталь, лучше прописать это в вопросе, потому что это накладывает сильные ограничения на ответ.

Comment: Соглашусь с @insolor без бэкенда тут никак, а github pages его не поддерживает.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Тогда, есть ли какой-то бесплатный хостинг, аналог github - pages? И стоит ли на него перейти?

Comment: С бесплатными хостингами сейчас туго, однако для небольших страниц можно найти за ~150 р/м. Только ищите с поддержкой php, если хотите реализовать вариант с ним.

Comment: Бесплатно - только статические страницы.

Comment: Тогда оставлю как есть. А если буду развиваться в этом направлении - буду что-то думать. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @T0hich71 на том же github pages можно использовать генератор статических сайтов jekyll, возможно вам подойдет

Comment: Возможно, но с этим нужно разобраться. Спасибо

Comment: @T0hich71 у beget бесплатно месяц и привязавывать карту не нужно

Comment: @EnderToy у https://beget.com/ru бесплатно месяц и привязавывать карту не нужно

Comment: Есть ещё https://www.openode.io/pricing - там бесплатно для opensource.